# Where to initialize bloc?

Tags: flutter, bloc

In one of my projects, I am using flutter_bloc package.

In that example, I instantiated bloc inside `didChangeDependencies()`. So bloc lives during the lifecycle of a screen.

However, my colleague told me not to initialize there. He said bloc should be initialized in `app.dart` where It can live over the lifecycle of the app. Because, in cases where there should be multiple screens on tablet, it will break the code.

For example, I have ScreenA, ScreenB and ScreenC. you can go to ScreenB and ScreenC through ScreenA. ScreenB and ScreenC use the same bloc, and bloc is initialized sepearately in each screens. He is saying that if the requirement is to show ScreenB and ScreenC simultaneously on a tablet, it might break the code. How?

Could you suggest me what is best? Or does it depend on the usecase?

Answer (score 0):

It is the best practice to initiate bloc instance during `initState` as it runs only once per widget lifecycle. `didChangeDependencies()` may be called multiple times for example if widget is moved in the widget tree or widget gets notified of `InheritedWidget` change, so bloc will get new instance like that and you dont want that. What your collegue is talking is more about `BlocProvider`s scope and sure is normal practice, but for some small-usecase-bloc might be redundant. That is up to you to decide does your whole app needs to be in scope of this bloc. Keep in mind that if `lazy` property is not set to false, your bloc will be created with the first call to it.

Comment: I got what he said about. But the point is that he suggested me not to initialize bloc in a particular screen because if there are multiple screens on a tablet's single screen, it will be problem. How can this be problem?

Comment: If you need bloc only in one screen, nothing bad to have it provided only to that screen, if it is multiple screens (and you need your bloc there too) other screens will have new `BuildContext` and your bloc will be out of scope (unless you pass bloc to new screen down widget tree with BlocProvider.value). Thats all, no other bad cases.

Comment: Main problem you described in a question is not about providers scope, it is that you create new bloc instance inside `didChangeDependencies()` when widget is not removed from the widget tree, so `dispose()` on old bloc instance is not called, and that itself leads to memory leak.

Comment: yeah, I understood that it should not be instantiated inside didChangeDependencies() and it is not my question. My question is why he said in tablets this usecase create problems? If it is not true, could you give me any source why it is not the case?